# How to use to_date function with c# datetime.now()

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I need to include time in the database with this sql statement
the code works but the time is missing

```
string query = "UPDATE
                  Pri_loc_payment
                SET 
                  PAYMENT_STATUS_ID = " + status + $", SERVICE_STATUS = {ServiceStatus}  PAYMENT_DATE  = TO_DATE( '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
                WHERE
                  ID in (" + concatIds + ")";
```

Comment: I think you should learn how to pass parameters into your queries, rather than munging query strings.

Comment: Use a parameter in the query instead of converting Now to String and then parsing string back to a DateTime Object.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Although I do agree with the previous comments, if you had to make something work you could try this:

```
string query = $"UPDATE Pri_loc_payment SET PAYMENT_STATUS_ID = 1, SERVICE_STATUS = { "SomeServiceStatus"}, PAYMENT_DATE = TO_DATE({DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd}) WHERE ID in ({"concatIds"})";
```